# How do you replace the first certain character in a string leaving the second character the same

Tags: vb.net, replace, character

I just need to know how to replace a the first certain character that appears in a string with a different character.

For example, I need to be able to change "need" to "noed" leaving the second 'e' the same.

What I have right now is changing "need" to "nood"

If you need any clarification please just ask me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use [IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the position of the "e".  Now [Insert()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String.Insert);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true) the "o" at that position and [Remove()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) the position immediately following that to remove the "e":

```
    Dim word As String = "need"
    Dim oldLetter As String = "e"
    Dim newLetter As String = "o"
    Dim index As Integer = word.IndexOf(oldLetter)
    If index <> -1 Then
        word = word.Insert(index, newLetter).Remove(index + 1, 1)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim findWhat As String = "ee"
    Dim searchThis As String = "need"
    Dim replaceWith As String = "o"
    Dim result As String = searchThis.Replace(findWhat, replaceWith & findWhat.Substring(1))
    Console.WriteLine(result)
```